# jQuery AJAX $get not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, get

This is my first attempt at AJAX, and so I'm keeping it simple. I've got a text file details.txt in the same folder as the index.html page.

The javascript I've got is as follows:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
  function getInfoFromServer() {
    $.get('details.txt', function(data) {
      $('#AJAXtest').html(data);
    });
}
</script>
```

And I'm calling that from a link as follows:

```
<a href="#" onClick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:getInfoFromServer()">Link</a>
```

And there's a div sitting nearby:

```
<div id="AJAXtest"></div>
```

The content of details.txt are:

```
test
```

I can't get this simple thing to work. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What do you see in the console?

Comment: Are you missing `$(document).ready(function() {` ?

Comment: Thanks SLaks, I saw in the console that the file was in the wrong folder. Fixed now.

Comment: just FYI, inline JavaScript is an outdated concept today, so instead of using `onmousedown`, please use jQuery's [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had put the text file in the wrong folder. I should have looked at the console. Sorry to bother you guys.

Answer (score 2):

Do you not want:

```
$('a').on('click', function() {
  $.get('details.txt', function(data) {
    $('#AJAXtest').html(data);
  });
  return false;
});
```

then

`<a href="#">Link</a>`

?

Comment: ok... well, you've fixed it now anyway - with a horrible document ready... i've edited my answer to be "better"